# Retrieving 'x' from seaching a string against a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, if-statement, search

I'm trying to print the value of 'x' from the dictionary (dict) after it has found a match from string (str) with any elements from the list (list).

```
>>> dict = {'c3750': 'switch', 'vsrx': 'vfirewall'}
>>> list = ['c3750', 'vsrx']               
>>> str = "Juniper Networks, Inc. firefly-perimeter internet router, kernel JUNOS 12.1X47-D15.4 #0: 2014-11-12 02:13:59 UTC     builder@chamuth.juniper.net:/volume/build/junos/12.1/service/12.1X47-D15.4/obj-i386/junos/bsd/kernels/VSRX/kernel Build date: 2014-11-12 "
>>> if any(x in str.lower() for x in list):        
...   print "{}".format(dict['x'])                 
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
KeyError: 'x'
```

Expected result: It should return 'vfirewall'.

Comment: Are you overriding all possible built-ins on purpose? It is better practice to avoid that

Comment: I don't get what you mean? May you please state a solution if you have one?

Comment: Negative: NameError: name 'x' is not defined

Comment: You should use an explicit loop for that

Answer (score 1):

Try should be what you are looking for:

```
dct = {'c3750': 'switch', 'vsrx': 'vfirewall'}
lst = ['c3750', 'vsrx']
s = "Juniper Networks, Inc. firefly-perimeter internet router, kernel JUNOS 12.1X47-D15.4 #0: 2014-11-12 02:13:59 UTC     builder@chamuth.juniper.net:/volume/build/junos/12.1/service/12.1X47-D15.4/obj-i386/junos/bsd/kernels/VSRX/kernel Build date: 2014-11-12 "

for x in lst:
    if x in s.lower():
        print("{}".format(dct[x]))
```

You should use a loop to search for every element in the list.

Comment: Thank you so so much!

Comment: To be equivalent to original code you should add a `break`

Comment: @Tomerikoo I see your point, but I am not sure if that is really what he is looking for

Comment: thanks @luigigi. that's the response I was looking for! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
dd = {'c3750': 'switch', 'vsrx': 'vfirewall'}
ll = ['c3750', 'vsrx']               
ss = "Juniper Networks, Inc. firefly-perimeter internet router, kernel JUNOS 12.1X47-D15.4 #0: 2014-11-12 02:13:59 UTC     builder@chamuth.juniper.net:/volume/build/junos/12.1/service/12.1X47-D15.4/obj-i386/junos/bsd/kernels/VSRX/kernel Build date: 2014-11-12 "

[dd[x] for x in ll if x in ss.lower()]

Out[1]:
    ['vfirewall']
```